# Can I use the same provision profile and distribution certificate for two Titanium Alloy projects

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-alloy

Can I use the same provision profile and distribution certificate for two projects built in Appcelerator Titanium Studio ?

The two projects are actually same so have the same AppID.

The reason for creating two projects is : while trying to do an upgrade to  my existing app in Apple App Store the webView stopped  working. As a workaround when I created a new project the and copy pasted the same code the webView started working.

So will I be able to use my existing distribution and provision profile certificates to push the upgrade (new Project in Titanium Studio) to AppStore?

Other details :
CLI version 3.4.2, Titanium SDK version 3.5.1.GA, Mac OS X, Version=10.10

Thanks in advance
Bably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they both have the same App ID, it's possible - probably even the only working way. If it's not the same App ID, you can also create Team Provisioning Profiles and Certificates.

Your WebView might work in the new project because of configuration differences e.g. in your tiapp.xml, Info.plist, project.xcconfig, ... file. You could check that.